# Convert DataModel to List in Java

Tags: java, list, datamodel

Can anybody tell me if its possible to convert a `DataModel` to an `ArrayList`?

And how can I do it? Please I have to know it as soon as possible!!!

I can convert the `ArrayList` to `ListDataModel` using `new ListDataModel(List list)`, but I don't know how to do the inverse!

ex:

```
public void filtrarCamadaPorCategoriaEFabricante(){
        this.listaDeCamadasParaEscolha = new ListDataModel<Camada>(this.service.getServiceComponentesConstrutivos().filtrarCamadaPorCategoriaEFabricante(idCategoriaDeCamadaASerAdicionada, idFabricanteDeCamadaAserAdicionada));
}
```

Comment: With the information you gave us the only answer is: have a look inside the documentation of The ListDataModel. Please provide some additional information, e.g. the package names of DataModel (and ArrayList if it is not java.util.ArrayList). If DataModel is an interface it might be a good idea to implement a kind of wrapper for an ArrayList that implements this interface.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like DataModel has an iterator
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#iterator()

You should be able to use this iterator to iterate the contents on the DataModel and create an ArrayList.